# How to read the data from the Key value pair list in Python

Tags: python

Can any one please help me on how to read the data from below list:

Input:

```
data = [{"Name": "Harry", "Age": 17}, {"Name": "Lil", "Age": 15}]
```

Expected Output:

```
Harry|17
Lil|15`
```

Comment: I suggest you learn about for loops and dictionaries in Python and attempt to solve the problem yourself. This is not a code writing service. We will answer specific questions when you encounter problems.

Comment: Show us what you've tried already. You should make an attempt at answering your own question before asking for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in data:
    print(f"{i['Name']}|{i['Age']}")
```